# r Shiny renderdatatable transpose data frame issue

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

When I use the renderdatatable function in Shiny to display a transposed dataset the function returns results with table column names missing.

[image]

Curious to find out what others have done to mitigate this problem, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a small reproducible example of this?. I posted an answer but now I realize I might have misunderstood something so some sample code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because the transposed dataset doesn't have any rownames (which will become column names after the transpose operation).
If you make sure to set column names for the data input the datatable render just fine for me.

```
library(shiny)

# Some data
n      <- 10
dat           <- data.frame("a"=sample(LETTERS,n),"b"=runif(n),"c"=runif(n))
rownames(dat) <-paste("r_", sample(LETTERS,n),sep="")
colnames(dat) <-paste("c_", sample(LETTERS,3),sep="")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8,dataTableOutput("tbl")),
    column(2,actionButton("renderMatrix","Render matrix")),
    column(2,actionButton("renderMatrixT","Render t(matrix)"))
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$renderMatrix,{
    output$tbl <- renderDataTable({dat})
  })
  observeEvent(input$renderMatrixT,{
    output$tbl <- renderDataTable({t(dat)})
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The examples sets both row names and column names so the data table will always have a "Column Name" column.

Comment: that worked by the row names are showing up as second column instead of first. They are on the right instead of showing up on the left...:( frustrating uh

Comment: can you post an example of this? because I'm not sure I can recreate this behavior

Comment: i was doing something wrong in the reactive function. I fixed it and its working fine. You made my day.

Comment: Great, glad I could help!